# Problem with exporting nested Rows/Columns to HTML

Tags: export, output-formatting, grid-layouts, html

I will show the problem on the following MWE:

```
Export["test.html",
       Column[{ Row[{"test", "1"}]  }],
       "HTML",
       "CSS" -> None]
```

> ```
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
> General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this 
> calculation. >>
> ```

Single `Row[{"test", "1"}]` without `Column` produces no error. Also let's assume I can't use `Grid`.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I have found exporting to HTML to be rather buggy in a lot of cases.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ah :( it is rather frustrating because `Grid[{{}}]` instead of `Row[{}]` behaves in different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

Using

```
ToBoxes@Column[{Row[{"test", "1"}]}]
```

we get

```
TagBox[GridBox[{{TemplateBox[{"\"test\"", "\"1\""}, "RowDefault"]}}, <<omitted output>>
```

That `TemplateBox` is strange because `Row` should have translated into `RowBox`. Let us force it:

```
kubaExport[x_] := ExportString[ ToBoxes@x
  /. TemplateBox[a_, "RowDefault"] :> RowBox[a] // RawBoxes,
  "HTML", "FullDocument" -> False];

kubaExport[Column[{Row[{"test", "1"}]}]]
```

yields what you need.

```
<table class='Output'>
 <tr style='vertical-align: baseline;'>
  <td style='text-align: left;'><span>test1</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

**First try**

`Export` with HTML is not happy with anything but cells. Ergo, wrap your objects in a cell. The following code works.

```
ExportString[Cell@ToBoxes@Column[{Row[{"test", "1"}]}], "HTML", "CSS" -> None]
```

Comment: You might notice that `Export` to HTML produces an empty page. That happens because the export functionality is (somewhat) broken for 2D content such as scripts, grids, etc. But that is another question.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to ask :) So the only difference is that there is not error, but still there is no html? I could use `Quiet` :)

Comment: @Kuba: Nope, that is not the only difference. Without the wrapping, Mathematica seems to try (and fails at) creating the 2D content with HTML tables.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't delete the answer permanently :) I will test this as soon as I get home. :)